# Assembly Bootloader Not Displaying Errors And Freezing

Tags: assembly, filesystems, kernel, bootloader

I'm a beginner Assembly programmer and I'm trying to write an x86 bootloader for a kernel. The main bootloader seems to work fine, but the secondary bootloader have some issues: it doesn't display error messages when kernel partition file system is missing/corrupted or when the kernel executable (kernel.bin) is not found. Something weird is going on with my bootloader. I attached both primary bootloader and secondary bootloader source codes. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

PRIMARY BOOTLOADER:

```
ORG 0x7c00

BITS 16

start:

    mov si, message

    call print

    mov ah, 2

    mov al, 1

    mov ch, 0

    mov dh, 0

    mov dl, 0x80

    mov bx, 0x8000

    mov cx, 3

    int 0x13

    jc disk_error

    mov si, buffer

    cmp byte [si + 0x8000], 0x00

    jnz secondary_bootloader_missing

    jmp 0x0000:0x8000

disk_error:

    mov si, disk_error_message

    call print

secondary_bootloader_missing:

    mov si, secondary_bootloader_missing_message

    call print

    cli

    hlt

print:

    mov bx, 0

loop:

    lodsb

    cmp al, 0

    je done

    call _print

    jmp loop

done:

    ret

_print:

    mov ah, 0x0E

    int 0x10

    ret

message:

    db "Bootloader", 0x0A, 0x0A, 0

disk_error_message:

    db "Disk error!", 0x0A, 0

secondary_bootloader_missing_message:

    db "Secondary bootloader not found - system halted!", 0x0A, 0

buffer:
    times 510-($ -$$) db 0
    db 0xAA55
```

SECONDARY BOOTLOADER:

```
ORG 0x8000

BITS 16

section .data

    buffer db 16 dup(0)

    pit_info db 16 dup(0)

    active_partition_info dw 0

 

section .text

    global start

start:

    mov ah, 0x00

    mov al, 0x03

    int 0x10

    mov si, starting_message

    call print

    mov ds, ax

    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, 0x01

    mov ch, 0x00

    mov dh, 0x00

    mov dl, 0x80

    mov bx, buffer

    int 0x13

    jc error_missing_pit

    xor cx, cx

    mov si, buffer

loop:

    mov ax, [si + 0x1C]

    test ax, ax

    jnz found_bootable

    add si, 16

    inc cx

    cmp cx, 0

    jz no_bootable

    jmp loop

found_bootable:

    mov di, pit_info

    mov cx, 16

    rep movsb

    mov ax, [si + 0x08]

    mov [active_partition_info], ax

    mov ax, [si + 0x0C]

    mov [active_partition_info + 2], ax

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov bh, 0x00

    mov dh, 0x01

    mov dl, 0x00

    int 0x10

    mov si, partition_found_message

    mov ax, 0x0000

    mov ds, ax

    call print 

    jmp kernel_load

error_missing_pit:

    mov si, missing_pit

    mov ax, 0x0000

    mov ds, ax

    call print

    cli

    hlt

no_bootable:

    mov si, no_partition

    mov ax, 0x0000

    mov ds, ax

    call print

    cli

    hlt

starting_message:

    db "Starting the operating system...", 0x0A, 0

missing_pit: 

     db "Partition Table error!", 0x0A, 0

no_partition:

     db "Kernel partition cannot be found - does it have the active flag?", 0x0A, 0

print:

    mov bx, 0

    call print_loop

    ret

print_loop:

    mov al, [si] 

    cmp al, 0 

    je print_done 

    mov ah, 0x0E 

    int 0x10 

    inc si 

    jmp print_loop

print_done:

    ret

kernel_load:

    mov ax, [active_partition_info]

    add ax, 19

    mov es, ax

    mov bx, 0

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, 1

    mov ch, 0

    mov dh, 0

    mov dl, 0x80

    mov si, boot_sector_buffer

    int 0x13

    mov si, file_system_signature

    mov cx, 3

    repe cmpsb

    jnz not_fat12

    jmp search_file

not_fat12:

    mov si, file_system_error_message

    call print

    cli

    hlt

boot_sector_buffer:

    times 512 db 0

file_system_signature:

    db 0x55, 0xAA

file_system_error_message:

    db "Unknown boot partition file system!", 0

search_file:

    mov cx, 11

    mov di, kernel_filename

    rep cmpsb

    je file_found

    add bx, 32

    cmp bx, 512

    jae file_not_found

    jmp search_file

file_found:

    mov ax, 0x1000

    mov cx, 8

    mov dx, ax

    mov bx, 0

    call read_file

    jmp 0x1000:0000

file_not_found:

    mov si, kernel_not_found_message

    call print

    cli

    hlt

read_file:

    pusha

    mov ax, cx

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, 1

    mov ch, 0

    mov dh, 0

    int 0x13

    jnc read_success

    stc

    popa

    ret

read_success:

    add dx, 512

    add bx, 1

    dec ax

    jnz read_loop

    popa

    ret

read_loop:

    pusha

    mov ax, cx

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, 1

    mov ch, 0

    mov dh, 0

    int 0x13

    jnc read_success

    stc

    popa

    ret

kernel_filename:

    db "KERNEL BIN", 0

kernel_not_found_message:

    db "Kernel file (kernel.bin) not found!", 0

 

partition_found_message:

    db "Kernel partition found!", 0x0A, 0
```

Comment: I don't know, just guessing... after `mov si, starting_message`, `call print`.... `ah = 0e` and `al = 0` and right after that program sets up `ds`, and `es`, these segments will have new addresses.

Comment: @Nassau Could you please explain more? If you are talking about ds and es, I don't think they cause problems (or do they?). Maybe there's a problem reading the Partition Table? Or the file system?

Comment: Offsets are calculated from start of the segments. If `ds = 0x0000` my memory dump shows `starting_message` is at `0x806e` and this combination is correct because message appears on my screen.  But if `ds = 0x0e00`, like in Your code, address of `starting_message` is calculated starting from new address of `ds`. Well, I have only zeros there, so nothing is printed on the screen, because 0 stops printing.

Comment: @Nassau Could you please tell me what should I change in my source code? I don't really understand where this issue starts from.

Comment: Add `mov ax, 0` in `SECONDARY BOOTLOADER` before `mov ds, ax`, `mov es, ax`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: @Nassau I have set AX to 0 before mov ds, ax and mov es, ax, and starting_message is still displayed as usual, but error messages or any other message is not displayed. I don't even know if the program actually reads the file system or not because it doesn't display any useful output. Everything I see on the virtual machine's screen is "Starting the operating system..." and the blinking cursor.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Bochs has a good built-in debugger that understands segmentation, or QEMU can act as a GDB-remote.  Then you don't have to guess about exactly what's happening or where something went wrong.  The time it takes to learn to use a debugger will pay for itself pretty quickly with asm; it's an essential tool.

Comment: I'm debugging this right now. :D I changed a little bit primary bootloader, but here `ah=0x02, int 0x13` reads only 3rd sector and there is `call print` which is in 2nd sector which is not loaded to memory. :D So maybe better solution is to load 2 sectors to `0x8000`. If I load 3rd sector to `0x8000` labels are shifted+512 bytes and points to wrong memory areas.

Comment: @Nassau Thank you. I have set AL to 0x03 (3) so it will load 3 disk sectors into memory (just to make sure everything is loaded). However, the secondary bootloader still acts strange - some error messages are not displayed, just like before, and this didn't fixed anything. Maybe I'm missing something?...

Comment: Well, one thing is for sure, You have to carefuly step through the code, check every value in registers and memory. After every `int 13h` do dump memory to see if code was correctly loaded to specific offset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this code and I found few bugs

1. Bootloader doesn't start because there is
   `db 0xAA55`. I changed this to `dw 0xAA55` and we are ready to go. ;)
2. Program reads (sector 3) which starts with `Unknown boot partition file system!`.
   So these sequence of bytes create some random instructions and this has nothing
   to do with the program. I started this sector with 'X' followed by `jmp label`.
3. `mov si, buffer`,`cmp byte [si + 0x8000], 0x00`. I assume this is location where code of second
   bootloader should be. `si = 0x7c93` + `0x8000` = `0xfc93`. `[0xfc93] = 0x00`.
   I don't know, maybe this should be `cmp byte [0x8000], 0x??` because we load sector
   to `0x8000`?? I inserted `X` at the beginning of sector 3 and if byte `0x8000` is diffrent than `X`
   this means this is not second bootloader.
4. I went step by step through the code and I noticed that labels in sector 3 are +512 bytes to far so
   I changed `org 0x8000` to `org 0x7e00`. Now label's offset is calculated correctly.
5. In `search_file:` I compare 10 bytes instead of 11 because `0` will be compared to `eb` and of course
   this will be error. Well, errors are also good because then I know messages are generated correctly. ;)
6. Error message didn't show because `print proc` is in sector 2 which is not loaded to memory.
   I switched to first file and I decided to load all sectors right away. I have kernel and 2nd bootoader in memory.
7. If `kernel_filename` is not found program prints `kernel_not_found_message` else we have code
   which further suppose to load another sector (8), which of course is not available.
   `es = 0`, `bx = 0`, `dl = 0`. Read from fdd to IVT. This generates error `ah = 20h`,
   File sharing violation. After this program returns, we have `jmp 0x1000:0000`. Jump to nothingness...
8. I assume sector 2 is kernel so I made jump to `0:800a`.
9. Ok, program prints `starting_message` and next we have read sector routine which generates
   `missing_pit`, Partition Table error!, `ah = 1`, Invalid function number. `buffer db 16 dup(21)` is
   16 bytes, read sector routine reads 512 bytes.
10. I made few corrections to make this code work.
    Image file which I run in qemu is combination of 3 files.

    `bootloader1.bin`       (sector 1)

    `bootloader2.bin`       (sector 2,3,4,5,6)

    `activepartition.bin`   (sector 7)

---

```
; bootloader1.bin

ORG 0x7c00

BITS 16

start:
    mov ah, 0x00                    ; text mode
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10

    xor ax, ax                      ; set up segments
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    mov si, message                 ; "Bootloader - stage 1" 
    call print

    mov ah, 2                       ; load all sectors
    mov al, 5
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov bx, 0x8000
    mov cx, 0x0002                      
    int 0x13

    jc disk_error

    mov si, stage2_bl_kernel        
    call print

    mov si, 0x8000              ; offset of kernel code
    cmp byte [0x8200], 'X'      ; check if this is correct bootloader - stage 2 sector

    jnz secondary_bootloader_missing
    jmp 0x0000:0x8201

disk_error:
    mov si, disk_error_message
    call print

secondary_bootloader_missing:
    mov si, secondary_bootloader_missing_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

print:
    mov bx, 0

loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je done
    call _print
    jmp loop

done:
    ret

_print:
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    ret

message:
    db "Sector 1 (Bootloader - stage 1) - loaded!", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0

disk_error_message:
    db "Disk error!", 0x0A, 0

secondary_bootloader_missing_message:
    db "Sector 3 (Bootloader - stage 2)", 0x0A, 0x0D
    db "Wrong sector - system halted!", 0x0A, 0x0D,0

stage2_bl_kernel:
    db "Sector 2 (Kernel)               - loaded!", 0x0A,0x0D
    db "Sector 3 (Bootloader - stage 2) - loaded!", 0x0A,0x0D,0     
buffer:
    times 510-($ - $$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

---

```
; bootloader2.bin

ORG 0x8000

BITS 16

section .data
    buffer db 512 dup('x')
    pit_info db 16 dup('z')
    active_partition_info dw 0x7878

section .text
    global start
; sector 2
db "KERNEL.BIN"
start:
    ;mov ah, 0x00
    ;mov al, 0x03
    ;int 0x10

    mov si, buffer + 508
    mov di, active_id
    mov cx, 4
    repe cmpsb

    jnz not_act_partition   

    mov si, correct_id
    call print  

    mov si, partition_table_entries
    call print  

    ; check partition table entries

    mov cx, 3
    mov al, 0x31
    mov bx, entry_num
    mov ah, [bx]
    mov si, buffer + 450 
    xor dx, dx              ; if 0 there is no system

    pt_entries:
        push si
        push ax
        push bx
    
        cmp al, [si]
        jz good_sys
        jb other_sys
    
        mov si, entry_msg
        call print 
        mov si, entry_num
        call print
        mov si, entry_msg_empty
        call print
    
        jmp entry_info_done
    
        good_sys:
            mov dx, si
            mov si, entry_msg
            call print 
            mov si, entry_num
            call print
            mov si, entry_msg_sys
            call print
        
            jmp entry_info_done
        
        other_sys:
            mov si, entry_msg
            call print 
            mov si, entry_num
            call print
            mov si, entry_msg_other_sys
            call print
        
            jmp entry_info_done
        
        entry_info_done:
            pop bx
            pop ax
            add ah, 1
            mov [bx], ah
            pop si
            add si, 16
            dec cx
    jnz pt_entries

    cmp dx, 0
    jz no_entry_info

    mov si, entry_found
    call print  

found_bootable:
    sub dx, 2               ; copy entry to pit_info
    mov si, dx
    mov di, pit_info
    mov cx, 16
    rep movsb

    mov ax, 0x4b4f
    mov [active_partition_info], ax

    mov si, starting_message
    call print  
        
    jmp 0x0000:0x8600
    
no_entry_info:  
    mov si, no_entry_info_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

not_act_partition:
    mov si, not_act_partition_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

error_missing_pit:
    mov si, missing_pit
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov ds, ax
    call print
    cli
    hlt

no_bootable:
    mov si, no_partition
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov ds, ax
    call print
    cli
    hlt

starting_message:
    db "Starting the operating system...", 0x0A,0x0D, 0

not_act_partition_message:
    db "Sector 5 (Active partition)", 0x0A,0x0D
    db "Incorrect Signature - system halted!", 0x0A,0x0D, 0

missing_pit: 
    db "Partition Table error!", 0x0A, 0

print:
    mov bx, 0
    call print_loop
    ret

print_loop:
    mov al, [si] 
    cmp al, 0 
    je print_done 

    mov ah, 0x0E 
    int 0x10 
    inc si 
    jmp print_loop

print_done:
    ret

kernel_load:
    mov ax, [active_partition_info]
    add ax, 19
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, 0
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 1
    mov ch, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0x80

    mov si, boot_sector_buffer
    int 0x13

    ;mov si, file_system_signature
    mov cx, 3
    repe cmpsb
    jnz not_fat12
    jmp search_file

not_fat12:
    mov si, file_system_error_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

boot_sector_buffer:
    times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0
;-------- sector 3
sector3_start:
db "X"              ; this is marker of 2nd bootloader
jmp search_file

file_system_error_message:
    db "Unknown boot partition file system!", 0

search_file:
    mov cx, 10
    mov di, kernel_filename
    rep cmpsb

    je kernel_found
    add bx, 32
    cmp bx, 512
    jae file_not_found
    jmp search_file

kernel_found:
    mov si, kernel_found_message
    call print

load_partition:
    mov ah, 0x02                
    mov al, 0x01
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x07
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x80    
    mov bx, buffer
    int 0x13
    jc load_failed

    mov si, act_part_loaded
    call print

    jmp 0x0000:0x800a

file_not_found:
    mov si, kernel_not_found_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

load_failed:
    mov si, load_failed_message
    call print
    cli
    hlt

kernel_filename:
    db "KERNEL.BIN", 0

active_id:
    db 0x41, 0x63, 0x74, 0x50           

kernel_not_found_message:
    db "Sector 2 (Kernel)",0x0A,0x0D
    db "Wrong sector - system halted!", 0x0A, 0x0D,0

kernel_found_message:
    db "Sector 2 (Kernel)               - correct sector!", 0x0A,0x0D, 0

load_failed_message:
    db "Sector 5 (Active partition)", 0x0A,0x0D
    db "Disk error!", 0x0A,0x0D, 0

act_part_loaded:
    db "Sector 5 (Active partition)     - loaded!", 0x0A,0x0D,0 

correct_id:
    db "Sector 5 (Active partition)     - correct signature!", 0x0A,0x0D,0

partition_table_entries:    
    db "Partition Table entries:", 0x0A,0x0D, 0 

no_entry_info_message:
    db "Sector 5 (Active partition)", 0x0A,0x0D
    db "Partition Table - All entries are incorrect!", 0x0A,0x0D, 0

entry_msg:   
    db "Entry ",0
 
entry_msg_empty:     
    db " - Free slot.",0x0A,0x0D,0

entry_msg_other_sys:    
    db " - Other system",0x0A,0x0D,0

entry_msg_sys:  
    db " - Good system <3",0x0A,0x0D,0  

entry_found:    
    db "Entry found!",0x0A,0x0D,0

entry_num:
    db 0x31,0x00

no_partition:
    db "Kernel partition cannot be found - does it have the active flag?", 0x0A, 0

    ;times 308 db 33
    ;boot_sector_buffer1:
    times 1022 - ($ - sector3_start) db 0x00
```

---

```
; activepartition.bin

ORG 0x8600

BITS 16

start:  
mov si, cmd
call print

system_stop:
    hlt
    jmp system_stop

print:
    mov bx, 0

loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je done
    call _print
    jmp loop

done:
    ret

_print:
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    ret

cmd:
    db "Cmd: > ", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0

    times 448-($ - $$) db 0
    ; PT0 - Empty entry
    ; PT1 - System
    ; PT2 - Other system
    db 'P','T','0','D','r','v',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
    db 'P','T','2','D','r','v',0x80,'O','t','h','e','r',' ','s','y','s'
    db 'P','T','1','D','r','v',0x80,'D','r','v','P','a','r','a','m','s'
    times 12 db 0
    dw 0x6341,0x5074        ; 7PAc
```

---

```
; makefile

BUILD_DIR = build
SRC_DIR = src
IMG_NAME = dev

dev: bl1 bl2 ap image
    C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-i386 -hda $(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img

image: $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader1.bin $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader2.bin
    @dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader1.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img bs=512
    @dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader2.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img bs=512 seek=1
    @dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)\activepartition.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img bs=512 seek=6

    @objdump -b binary -m i8086 -M intel -D $(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img
    @hexdump -C $(BUILD_DIR)\$(IMG_NAME).img    

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader1.bin $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader2.bin

bl1:
    nasm -g -fbin $(SRC_DIR)\bootloader1.asm -o $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader1.bin
bl2:
    nasm -g -fbin $(SRC_DIR)\bootloader2.asm -o $(BUILD_DIR)\bootloader2.bin
ap:
    nasm -g -fbin $(SRC_DIR)\activepartition.asm -o 
    $(BUILD_DIR)\activepartition.bin
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this and see if it works. Thanks again! :)

Comment: By the way, your code expects the kernel to have an executable named "KERNEL.BIN" in the active partition's root, right?

Comment: Yeah. This is some kind of header of the file. Change one letter and code will generate error messages. Same thing is with bootloader 2, sector doesn't start with X so this means someone made changes to code or copied something by mistake to this location or whatever the reason.

Comment: I have tested your code. It seems to work. But here's a few small issues with it:

Comment: - It display "Secondary bootloader found", even if it wasn't found, then display "Secondary bootloader not found - system halted".

Comment: And the most important thing, if the disk doesn't have any partition table, the bootloader hallucinate that there's a partition table and try to load the kernel, even if not possible

Comment: I created an active FAT12 partition on the disk image using fdisk, however your bootloader doesn't seem to detect that it is not formated/doesn't contain any kernel. It just displays the same "Starting the operating system..." output.

Comment: I don't have Your image file. I just work with 2 files You posted. And title says "not displaying errors and freezing". So I thought something is wrong with program flow. I don't know what is Your goal You want to reach. Just write Your own code and use debugger a lot. :))

Comment: Program misbehaves because probably I forgot to add 0 after one of the messages. I created in `activepartition.bin` some fictional partition table and if third position of each entry is diffrent than 1 program generates `Sector 5 (Active partition), Partition Table - All entries are incorrect!`.

Comment: Alright, I will try to find out what's wrong by myself. I don't really care about chaotic messages and outputs as long as the bootloader load the kernel. After all, that's it's main porpose :)

Comment: Don't worry, you added 0 after the messages. There's something else going on. The message logic itself doesn't look too wrong